# React Styled Components styles do not apply properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have problem with understanding how cascade style sheet algorithm works with React library styled-component. I have created Todo element with 3 fields, and I gave each its own class , like TodoTitle, TodoDescription and TodoAction - so that div with different class will have diferent width. Yet width property does not apply to class, even though it is flex. Other properties like red backgound did aplied.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Todo } from '../../types/Todo';
import { StyledTodoItem } from './TodoItem.styles';

type Props = {
  todo: Todo;
  index: number;
};

export const TodoItem: React.FC<Props> = ({ todo, index }) => {
  return (
    <StyledTodoItem bg={index % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}>
      <div className="todoTitle">
        <h1>{todo.title}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="todoDescription">
        <h1>{todo.text}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="todoAction">
        <button type="button">Hello</button>
      </div>
    </StyledTodoItem>
  );
};
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

type Props = {
  bg: 'even' | 'odd';
};

export const StyledTodoItem = styled.div<Props>`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: ${({ bg }) => (bg === 'odd' ? 'white' : '#ededed')};
  height: ${({ theme }) => theme.todoTable.elementMinHeight};
  border-right: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.borderColor};

  .todoTitle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
  }
`;
```

If , instead of `.todoTitle` I paste `div` , width will be applied, but for every element.
Please, explain how to fix this and any similar problem like this that might arise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey! can you give css for todoDescription and todoAction classes? this would really help me, though it looks like you need to apply 'flex-shrink: 0' to .todoTitle

Comment: Hi. With styled-components all css is written in javascript/typescript, here in second code display.

Comment: Everything seems to work as intended https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-tharp-bbdyci?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. So I checked out few tutorials and it seems that best practice is to avaid as possible html tags and to change them for custom styled components as provided in example. Also nested components do lead to lots of bugs, or so it seems.

```
return (
    <>
      <TodoItemWrapper bg={index % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}>
        <TodoTitle>
          <TextTitle>{todo.title}</TextTitle>
        </TodoTitle>
        <TodoDescr>
          <TextDescr>{todo.text}</TextDescr>
        </TodoDescr>
       <TodoAction>
          <Button>View</Button>
          <Button>Edit</Button>
          <Button>Delete</Button>
        </TodoAction>
      </TodoItemWrapper>
)
```

```
export const TodoItemWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: ${({ bg }) => (bg === 'odd' ? 'white' : '#ecfcff')};
  height: fit-content;
`;

export const TodoText = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
`;

export const TodoTitle = styled(TodoText)`
  width: ${({ theme }) => theme.todoTable.title};
  border-right: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.borderColor};
`;
```